# passing a value from an activity to popup window

Tags: android, popup

how can I pass a value from an activity to popup window ? though it seems a silly question. The code snippet is as given below. All I need to pass a value from the function onButtonPopup() to the popup window (shape_details.xml). thanks in advance.

```
public void onButtonPopup(View target, int position) {
    // Make a View from our XML file
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shape_details, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llShapeDetails));

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();




    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, width - width / 4, height - height / 3, true);

    pw.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: *I need to pass a value from the function onButtonPopup() to the popup window* : which value u want to pass?

Comment: say, a string value to be passed, which will be displayed as a header text in the popup window.

Comment: see this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Comment: you didn't get my point. I saw this link before. This is all about opening a static popup window, where in content is fixed.

Comment: @NeomatSmith : then you are getting any issue by accessing TextView from PopupWindow and set it's value dynamically ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K yes, exactly so.

Comment: @NeomatSmith : what issue u are getting . you have an TextView in shape_details layout ?

Comment: Finally I solved it myself. Thanks every1 :)

Comment: @Neomat Smith : Can you share how you solve it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

To send/pass any value from any Activity we need Two activity. Like the first one is "MainActivity" and the second one is "PopUpWindowActivity". Now, we create "PopUpWindowActivity".

```
  public class PopUpWindowActivity {
  public void onButtonPopup(final View target, int position) {
    //You can work here with "position"
    }
  }
```

Now we will send/pass value from "MainActivity"

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           //onCreate Metod and other work here
           //Here we will send/pass data to "PopUpWindowActivity"
           SampleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    PopUpWindowActivity popUpWindow = new PopUpWindowActivity();
                    popUpWindow.onButtonPopup(view, 1);
                    //I take position value is 1. You can send your own.
                }
            });
    }
```